Error when using Morgan in NestSJ - "TypeError: (0 , morgan_1.default) is not a function"
I was trying to use morgan to log requests in a NestJS rest api, but ran into this...
For context, this file is on /src/middlewares/request-logging.ts, and my main.ts looks like:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

import { useRequestLogging } from './middleware/request-logging';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.enableCors();
  useRequestLogging(app);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();

Error:
TypeError: (0 , morgan_1.default) is not a function

Code:
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import morgan from 'morgan'
import { format } from 'morgan';

export function useRequestLogging(app) {
    const logger = new Logger('Request');
    app.use(
        morgan('tiny', {
            stream: {
                write: (message) => logger.log(message.replace('\n', '')),
            },
        }),
    );
}


Probably
import * as morgan from 'morgan';

should work. Or try specifying esModuleInterop: true in the tsconfig.json.
